# Best method for applying user configuration values across multiple files (Docker, Python, Ansible, and Bash)?

Tags: python, bash, docker, ansible, configuration-files

Project Description:
I have a project that uses Docker Swarm to create an infrastructure for a distributed application to run on. That application is composed of Python and bash files (everything is Linux oriented). To bootstrap this whole project, I'm using Ansible to build the containers, push files around, and verify environments on each target Swarm node.

Problem:
Because this is an application I'm trying to make (relatively) user friendly for tech savvy type people, I'd like to have just one configuration file they can fill out. But I'm a little stuck on how to then take these values (some of which are inter-dependent across Bash/Python/Docker) and actually fill in the real values.

What's the best way to approach this? I've been considering making a few Python parsers that Ansible kicks off to fill in everything, but I've been reluctant to jump on that.

Comment: Without providing specific and narrow questions about a technical problem you encountered trying to solve this yourself (with [mcve]s to let others reproduce and test), this is rather too broad to be answerable.

Comment: That said, *personally*, I'm a big fan of Nix -- doing things the Nix way, one can directly build Docker containers ("directly" meaning without using Docker itself at all -- [`dockerTools`](https://nixos.org/nixpkgs/manual/#sec-pkgs-dockerTools) is a set of tooling that builds Docker-compliant containers) with the same content that's exposed on the host, and/or pushed to other systems using NixOps.

Comment: Or possibly [Ansible's `--extra-vars @file.yaml` option](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#passing-variables-on-the-command-line) is what you're looking for; but without a clearer description of your setup (the Ansible + Swarm combination sounds funny) it's a little hard to tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python, Docker and Ansible all have, at minimum, read access to the environment. `export` your variables from Bash, then access them independently from each application. I would put serious effort into minimizing interdependence, since I don't know that you can write to the environment from these applications.

edit:
Bash does not support `env`ironmental arrays, but, rather than clog up your environment with many related variables, you can export delimited strings:

`export my_string='key=value:user=Bob:multiple_keys=one,two,three'`

This is an exercise in good planning and documentation. Think carefully about how this string will grow as your script develops.

See `$ env |awk '/^(PATH|LS_COLORS)=/' ORS=\\n\\n` for two native examples of delimited strings.

Comment: In [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), note the section "Answer Well-Asked Questions", and the section therein regarding questions which "are unclear or lacking specific details that can uniquely identify the problem". In general, if someone other than the OP can't conclusively test whether your answer solves the OP's problem, the question is too vague to be answerable.

Comment: So, are you suggesting something like a big key=value environments file that would then load into each container's env? Cause that actually sounds like a way easier approach than what I had in mind.

Comment: @Bob, I would suggest exporting a delimited string, which you can parse using the target application's regular expression tools. Please see my edit for examples.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I'm interested in this problem. If the question is severely opposed to the nature of this board, then you won't have trouble removing it.

Comment: @vintnes, I also did not know about the delimited strings, so thanks for pointing that out. I'm probably going to use a mixture of the bash env strings and these delimited arrays. I'm not overly worried about cluttering up my ENV since these are dedicated lightweight containers running just one or two Python/Celery workers (which each contain maybe two or so functions).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, my apologies for not giving you enough specifics, but I'm at the same time trying to frame a solution in my head for this. As it is now, there are multiple disparate frameworks in play, so it's not about how each one works, but how to configure them at a high level from something like a shared config file (or better).